# How to improve XML schema with sub-elements or references?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-schema-collection

I have a xml schema like the one being shown below but I have noticed that it would be very complicated to maintain.

I want to improve the current schema in one of the following ways but I am not sure if they would be the best/correct route:

**Option 1:** Use a reference of all elements of `movieDetails` within `movies`.

**Option 2:** Add `movieDetails` as a sub-element of `movies` (which I frankly am struggling to achieve)

Which route would be best and what would be the best way to structure it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    targetNamespace="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/AmazingMovies"
                    xmlns:tns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/AmazingMovies"
                    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:complexType name="movies">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Director" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Year" type="xsd:int"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="movieDetails">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Actor" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="numberOfCast" type="xsd:int"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="releaseDate" type="xsd:date"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="OnDisplay">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence >
                <xsd:element name="collectionOfMovies" type="tns:movies" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

**Extra information**

> `OnDisplay` element would add all elements of `movies` into a list in order to use them when unMarshalling. However, I want to also add `movieDetails` onto `OnDisplay`, therefore, it would be convenient to have them included in `movies` as a ref, sub-element or another form.

**Tried the following methods but failed XML validation**

> Method 1

```
<xsd:element name="MoviesAndDetails">
    <xsd:complexType name="movies">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Director" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Year" type="xsd:int"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="movieDetails">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Actor" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="numberOfCast" type="xsd:int">     </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="releaseDate" type="xsd:date"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

> Method 2

```
<xsd:complexType name="MoviesAndDetails">
    <xsd:complexType name="movies">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Director" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Year" type="xsd:int"/>
            <xsd:element ref="Actor"/>
            <xsd:element ref="numberOfCast"/>
            <xsd:element ref="releaseDate"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="movieDetails">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Actor" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="numberOfCast" type="xsd:int">     </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="releaseDate" type="xsd:date"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a `movieDetails` element as a child of `collectionOfMovies`, then you could add a `movieDetails` element of type `tns:movieDetails` to the sequence of `movies` elements.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/AmazingMovies"
  xmlns:tns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/AmazingMovies"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xsd:complexType name="movies">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Director" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Year" type="xsd:int"/>
        <xsd:element name="movieDetails" type="tns:movieDetails"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="movieDetails">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Actor" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="numberOfCast" type="xsd:int"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="releaseDate" type="xsd:date"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:element name="OnDisplay">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence >
            <xsd:element name="collectionOfMovies" type="tns:movies" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you... That's exactly what I needed. Just didn't know how to add another element as a child element.

Comment: I would like to receive one more input from you if possible... I was able to create a JAXB Binding in order to unMarshall the XML. I have created the object as follows  `OnDisplays todaysShow = new Ondisplays();
        List<movies> movies_today =  todaysShow.getMovieCollection();`       Nonetheless, I am able to set elements such as `Title`, `Director` and `Year`, however, I thought that I would be able to also set elements of movieDetails this way but it only presents `setmovieDetails` and not the elements contained in it. How can I achieve this?